# Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm was halfway setting WiFi router for my Raspberry Pi but this appeared:

Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See

> "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I've tried to excude systemctl status hostapd.service:

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-11 15:50:37 JST; 1s ago
  Process: 1673 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=ex

 7月 11 15:50:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA
 7月 11 15:50:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
 7月 11 15:50:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm new to Raspberry Pi. Would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today is the second time I've successfully set up a Raspberry Pi 0 W access point.  This time i had this error:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

After retracing my steps I found that i had made an error in the /etc/default/hostapd file.

I simply forget to enter the ending quotation " symbol at the end of the DAEMON_CONF string.

Also, the driver for the rpi0w in the hostapd.conf file should be nl80211, not brcmfmac.

You've likely made a simple error like I did.  Check all your edits.

I've used this site's instructions for my setup

```
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md
```

[image: MyAP]

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error happen to me - lengthening the PSK to >= 8 characters resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A trick to get a more specific error is to run the line of code pointed to by `ExecStart`:

```
/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}
```

Fill in `$DAEMON_OPTS` and `${DAEMON_CONF}` with whatever values you have configured in `/etc/default/hostapd.conf`.  Now you will see a better error, like mispelling of a config or a bad driver.